# How to use css transition correctly?

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to make a hidden div to be reavelead using transition but I mess things up and it doesn't work.

I got a div on top of another but I have it hidden using the visibility property. Now when I hover over the bottom div (.hexagon) I have the top div (.product-text) displayed. Everything works just fine. Although I want to make it a little bit smoother using a transition, but it just doesn't work.

The css (I'm using Sass) :

(the bottom div):

```
.hexagon {
position: relative;
background-color: black;
width: 240px; 
height: 138.56px;
margin: 69.28px 0;
border-left: solid 5px $honey;
border-right: solid 5px $honey;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
img{
    height:100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
&:hover{
    background-color:white; 
    cursor: pointer;

    .product-text{
        visibility: visible;
        transition: visibility 3s;
    }
}
```

}

.....

(the top div):

```
.product-text{
text-align: center;
font-size:18px;
color: black;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px $honey;
border-radius: 7px;
font-weight:bold;
opacity: 0.8;
z-index:2;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
visibility:hidden;
background-color: rgba(15, 1, 1, 0.555);

p{
    margin:0em;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't transition `visibility` (nor any other *binary* property). What you can do is an `opacity` transition.

```
.hexagon {
    &:hover {
        .product-text {
            opacity: 1;
         }
    }
}

.product-text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}
```

You probably want the `transition` property applied directly to the class and not to the hover state.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works just fine! Thanks for your help!